# How does redux state changes but component doesn't

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux

I'm writing a independent modal using React and Redux. I pass from my environment variable if modal is visible and initial position and the rest of the state in redux store.

I've tried using react lifecycle methods to force update my app but nothing seems to work.

This is how I connect my App with store:

render() {
    const {
      media, initPosition, isMobile, title, isVisible, onClose
    } = this.props;

```
const photos = media.filter(
  item => typeof item.video === 'undefined'
);
const videos = media.filter(
  item => typeof item.video !== 'undefined'
);
const initState = {
  media: {
    items: media,
    filteredItems: {
      all: media,
      photos,
      videos
    },
    filter: 'all',
    initPosition,
    currentPosition: initPosition
  },
  gallery: {
    isMobile,
    title
  }
};

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App onClose={e => onClose(e)} isVisible={isVisible} />
  </Provider>
);
```

I call my modal like this:

```
<Gallery
      media={videos.concat(photos)}
      isMobile={isMobile}
      isVisible={show}
      onClose={() => this.setState({ show: false })}
      initPosition={position}
      changePosition={position => this.setState({ position })}
      title="Maximus"/>
```

And this is how I connect it to the state:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { media, gallery } = state;
  const {
    filteredItems, filter, currentPosition, initPosition
  } = media;
  const { isMobile, title } = gallery;
  return {
    filteredMedia: filteredItems,
    filter,
    currentPosition,
    initPosition,
    isMobile,
    title
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    changeMediaProp
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  GalleryApp
);
```

After isVisible is changed nothing seem to work with redux store. It is changing, but the app isn't updating.

When I toggle modal (change isVisible prop), redux state keeps changing, but my app isn't rerendering.

So to sum it up. I change isVisible and initPosition from surrounded application( these props are not stored in store), and when I changed them my component can't react to changes from reducer store.

Comment: How do you connect the app to the Redux store?

Comment: Are you using react-redux? If yes, are you using `connect`?
You should post the code for the `Gallery` component so we have these answers and are able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I was passing multiple stores to my application. I fixed it by saving store in constructor and not creating it multiple times.

```
 let newStore = store;
    if (!newStore) {
      newStore = createStore(
        reducer,
        initState,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
      );
      this.setState({ store: newStore });
    }


    return (
      <Provider store={newStore}>
        <App onClose={e => onClose(e)} isVisible={isVisible} />
      </Provider>
    );
```

Does anyone have any better solution?

Comment: There are react-redux methods to combine reducers, so you have a single store. save your store in a file and import it into the main component so you have a single store as explained here, https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers read more about common gotchas here https://getstream.io/blog/react-redux-best-practices-gotchas/

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have enough information to know. Are you using connect and react-redux. Here's a good intro if you need some help.

https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/

An example component would look like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const TodoItem = ({ todo, destroyTodo }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {todo.text}
      <span onClick={destroyTodo}> x </span>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todo: state.todos[0]
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    destroyTodo: () =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'DESTROY_TODO'
      })
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(TodoItem)
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question with more information (how I connected the app with store and how to connect single component with store.